# Why is the Common Language Runtime a virtual machine?

Tags: c#, virtual-machine, clr

While researching C#, I came across the following statement on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime):

> The Common Language Runtime (CLR), the virtual machine component of Microsoft's .NET framework, manages the execution of .NET programs.

This might be a newbie question, but from what I know a virtual machine is just an emulation of an OS. Why is the CLR considered a virtual machine?

Comment: VM means too many things.  Maybe it helps to think of it as a virtual processor that can execute an assembly language called MSIL and doesn't require manual memory management like real processors do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to feel a little confused over this. The term virtual machine can have different meanings and is sometimes used to refer to the emulation of a hardware setup. Like you say, often they are used to run multiple operating systems on a single machine.

However, confusingly, the term virtual machine also refers to software that is responsible for translating byte code(artificial, more portable machine instructions) into real native machine code at runtime. Moreover, they are responsible for managing the runtime of a program (By for example releasing back memory automatically, without the need for the programmer to get involved, this is known as garbage collection).

The common language runtime is a virtual machine in the latter sense of the word.

CLR is similar to JVM (Java Virtual Machine). JVM is the virtual machine that is used to run Java programs. The .Net assemblies (Dlls and Exes) are not executed directly by the OS but is executed by an intermediary level called CLR which translates the .NET assembly into native executable code. This architecture has the advantage that the .NET programs don't need to be recompiled for different OSs (Linux, Unix), if a virtual machine is installed on that OS then the .NET program should run like it is (built on Windows for example). Another virtual machine for .NET is Mono. Here is Mono: http://www.mono-project.com/.